# Поля при создании таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql

Создаю таблицу. В таблице будут находится новости. Вопрос лишь в том, как правильно сделать.
Пишу поля **Анонс**, **Полный текст**, **Дополнительные файлы**, **Дополнительные изображения**.

```
create table table_name(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ANONS_TEXT VARCHAR(255),
    DETAIL_TEXT VARCHAR(3000),
    FILE_L VARCHAR(755),
    ADDITIONAL_PHOTO VARCHAR(755)
);
```

Верно ли я указал используя `VARCHAR` ?

Ведь  в `DETAIL_TEXT` может быть и большой объем текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-text/

1. TEXT – 64KB (65,535 символов)
2. MEDIUMTEXT – 16MB (16,777,215 символов)
3. LONGTEXT – 4GB (4,294,967,295 символов)